# How to separate renderPlot calls in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I want to separate components of my Shiny application into individual files, starting from total app.R. I would like to have component_1.R, component_2.R etc.

But it seems difficult to simply write functions and separate the server logic. There is a function called moduleServer to write modules, but I don't see a way to use it in my scenario.
How to put reactives() and renderPlot({}) functions in separate files and integrate them into the main server.R ?

```
ui <- fluidPage(..plotOutput("barplot"), ...)

server <- function(input,output,session){
   sqlOutput <- reactive({ .. })
   output$barplot <- renderPlot({ sqlOutput() ..})
   output$barplot2 <- renderPlot({ sqlOutput() ..})
  # Many more different reactives() and output$plot ..

}
```

Comment: Hi, I think [this article](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html) answers your questions

Answer (score 0):

I you don't see a need for modules, you can source `server` functions from a separate file, for example `server_functions.R`:

```
#server_functions.R
library(dplyr)
getData <- function(cylinput) {#create dataframe according to input
   mtcars %>% filter(cyl = cylinput) }

renderData <- function(data) {
   renderPlot(plot(data))
}
```

In server.R:

```
source('server_functions.R')

data <- reactive({getData(input$cyl)})

output$myplot <- renderData(data())
```

This already makes server code much more readable.